# How do I get a cloned project into my own github repository?

Tags: github

Normally I get the project easily to github, but now that the project base has been cloned so I can't push it to my own repo for some security reasons.

I cloned project base using the terminal command

`git clone https://github.com/username/project.git`

Can anyone help with this? or link to a page where a solution can be found?

Comment: Are you an owner or collaborator of the project that you cloned?

Comment: Also please mention what commands you have tried for pushing the cloned project to your own repo after the clone command you have mentioned? And what is the error shown?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I think you are looking to [fork](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo)?  If so, you will want to fork the original repo, and then clone your fork of it.

If that isn't what you are looking for, my next guess is you want to make the original project a dependency in your personal project.  In which case, the solution will depend on your specific tech stack.